# Java Hadoop, how to save mapper output to HDFS in addition to Reducer output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running across a situation where I have to post-process the results of the mapper output into my MySQL database for further visualization. So I need to have a single Hadoop (3.0) Map/Reduce job output both the contents of the mapper and the reducer on output. I've done a lot of searching but I haven't seen a good solution to this problem other then running the map/reduce job first, then running another map only job. If I didn't have to run the job twice to output the results of both stages it would save a lot of grief.  Is there an easy "setSaveMapperResults(true)" function I could call that I'm just not seeing??? Thanks everyone.

Comment: You could use Oozie or Airflow to coordinate that whole process instead of just running those stages yourself. But to answer the question, the mapper output is written to the disk, but not in the final output location

Comment: Is there any way to have Hadoop save both the mapper output AND the reducer output?

Comment: Other than having a map-only job, then a map-reduce job, not that I know of

Comment: You can output the same mapper data to a different location using MultipleOutputs. See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html .